# Does WSO2 Identity Server expose an endpoint/URI for XACML requests?

Tags: wso2

Does anyone know if the WSO2 Identity Server exposes a web service endpoint/URI to which I can send XACML requests via HTTP(S)?  I am aware that they provide an API for doing this, but I have a situation where I can't use that, but I can do HTTP requests.

Thanks,
Jim

P.S.  For the record, I think I've found my answer, mostly deduced from this page:

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/11/fine-grained-xacml-authoriation-with-pip-points/

That page tells how to enable WSO2 to unhide the WSDL for the EntitlementService web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enable the entitlement service wsdl and call it from external systems according to your requirement to send requests. By default this admin service is disabled. You can read more about it at [PDP PEP Communication – how WSO2 Identity Server defines](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/13/pdp-pep-communication-wso2is/)